# Footer cover part of body content

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a page that has a header and footer. For some reason, the footer is covering part of the body content no matter how I modify the footer css. Currently, my css is

```css
       html {
          height: 100%;
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        
        body {
          position: relative;
          margin: 0;
          padding-bottom: 6rem;
          min-height: 100%;
        }
        
        .navbar {
          margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
        
        .footer {
          width:100%;
          height:6%;
          position: absolute;
          right: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          left: 0;
          padding: 1rem;
          background-color: #efefef;
        }
```

```html
    <footer class="footer fixed-bottom navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="text-muted text-strong">Copyright (c) information and other stuff</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

Could someone point me to how to fix that problem?
Also, a side topic, but how could I adjust the width of the button, so they have the same width (for Revoke/Grant Access buttons).
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Mate, you need to post your HTML code (additionally to CSS).

Comment: It has nothing to do with my HTML code, but I edited it in my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code snippet below the classes `mb-5 pb-5` have been added to the preceding container to achieve the desired effect. No custom css necessary in this case.

`mb-5` means "margin-bottom 5 units" and `pb-5` means "padding-bottom 5 units".

Click the "run code snippet" button below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container mb-5 pb-5">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-6">
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum et odio quibusdam laudantium amet, laboriosam soluta saepe dolorem ratione, iusto, illo eaque. Fuga unde, natus labore delectus laboriosam voluptatibus eligendi quod ratione soluta quos autem, fugiat ex nesciunt aliquam pariatur in, beatae, maiores sapiente cumque ipsa maxime! Velit deserunt aliquid cupiditate tempora quidem voluptatem harum. Reiciendis iusto iste mollitia, quo reprehenderit laborum unde praesentium molestias. Quibusdam incidunt officia a, ea, animi eos atque ratione facere, temporibus necessitatibus quidem iure deleniti. Cupiditate similique laboriosam perspiciatis eaque odit provident libero fugiat est dicta, praesentium voluptas amet asperiores incidunt doloribus officiis itaque! Necessitatibus libero.
       </div>
   </div>
</div>

<footer class="footer fixed-bottom navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
        <p class="text-muted text-strong">Copyright (c) information and other stuff</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please apply `padding` bottom of `body` selector according `footer` height. Suppose you set height in your `footer` `height:6%;` so you need to padding bottom 6% then you can reach at content of bottom.

This should work for you:

```
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 6rem;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding-bottom; 6%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably way easier to make the footer not have absolute positioning. Otherwise you would need to make sure the body has `padding-bottom` to the same height as the footer.